# iOS: Default status bar style with UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance YES

Tags: ios, uiappearance, ios7-statusbar

*Is there a way how to set the default status bar style while keeping the `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` enabled?*

Here is the problem, I'm dealing with:

Nearly the whole app needs to be using `UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent` as the navigation bar has a dark background. Originally, `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` was disabled and the following was set in in `Info.plist` for while text status status bar:

```
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
```

This worked just fine until I found out that this `.LightContent` status bar is shown even for some of the share extensions, like Facebook Messenger, causing it to be unreadable:

[image: Facebook Messenger Share Extension light status bar style]

This could be solved by using `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance`, but then I would need to add the following method to all of view controllers which I want to avoid as the app is quite large.

Moreover, for the one screen in the app that has light nav bar background, I was switching to dark nav bar using `UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle()` but this method in deprecated in iOS 9.

Any ideas how to solve this? Swizzling?

Comment: I did a workaround and used this line of code for updating status bar color: `        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.black` you would want to set it to `UIBarStyle.default` I think

Comment: A possible hacky workaround (not tested) that comes to mind is, instead of adding that method to all the view controllers, writing an extension for the ViewController class, that contains that method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Solution

The easiest and cleanest way how to achieve that is to add the following line in `AppDelegate`'s `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = .Black
```

This will make `.LightContent` as the default status bar style thorough the app as long as your app uses `UINavigationController`.

Don't forget to keep the following setting in app's `Info.plist` if want to use `.LightContent` status bar style during launch for splash screen:

```
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
```

#### TL;DR

My current setup, which is very similar to many other apps, uses `UITabBarController` as the top most controller with `UINavigationController` stack for each tab.

`UINavigationController` takes care of the status bar style (as it should) and do not call `preferredStatusBarStyle()` on its child view controllers. Therefore, implementing the [subclassing solution proposed by par](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41926252/1161723) does not work in my case.

Further subclassing the custom subclass of `UINavigationController` [I'm using](https://github.com/thefuntasty/TFTransparentNavigationBar) would not be a clean solution either.

Now, since the app has `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` enabled and correct status bar style everywhere in the app itself, `SFSafariViewController` and share extension like Messages, Mail, etc use the correct (`.Default`) status bar style too.

The only exception where the correct status bar style is not used is the Facebook Messenger's share extension mentioned in the question. However, it seems to be a bug in the extension itself as all apps I have tried that use `.LightContent` status bar style (like Twitter, for example) have the same issue - presented FB Messenger share extension from the app has a status bar with white color text.

Answer (score 3):

A solution I use quite frequently is to create a base view controller class that all view controllers in my app derive from.  This has the advantage of allowing use of the view-controller-based status bar style-setting functionality with a default (light or dark) style, which can then be overridden on a per-view-controller basis as necessary.

A base view controller is also really handy once you start getting into trait-collection based changes, custom transition animations that you want for most view controllers, a central point for analytics tracking, and other useful things.

Yes, you have to go through your potentially large source base and change all your `UIViewController`s into `BaseViewController`s, but this is often as easy as a global search-and-replace.

Here's what the `BaseViewController` looks like with status-bar related methods:

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
    var statusBarHidden: Bool = false { didSet { setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate() } }
    var statusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle = .lightContent { didSet { setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate() } }
    var statusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation = .fade { didSet { setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate() } }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle { return statusBarStyle }
    override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation { return statusBarUpdateAnimation }
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool { return statusBarHidden }
}
```

For all view controllers that use the default light style, you don't need to do anything special:

```
class ViewController: BaseViewController { }
```

In the cases where you need a dark status bar, do:

```
class DarkStatusBarViewController: BaseViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        statusBarStyle = .default
    }
}
```

Note also that you could rename the `DarkStatusBarViewController` above to `DarkStatusBarBaseViewController` and derive from it instead of `BaseViewController` when you need a dark status bar. Then you don't need to duplicate the status bar code in every view controller that needs it and you maintain a nice linear relationship for all your `BaseViewController` functionality.